# PouchDB security concerns, client-side permission logic

Tags: electron, pouchdb

I'm new to PouchDB but want to use it in my recent project. The main concern is of course security. I'd like to build a multiuser, desktop app (Electron-based) that allow users to modify documents in the same pouch/couch DB.
Because of some workflows some parts of the same documents should only be change by particular users. As I understand the only way to do it in Javascript/Pouchdb app is to add permission logic to client side JS, and that dosen't sound secure at all. Am I right? What is the real thread here? How easy it is to bypass client-side js permissions and change pouchdb document in an unauthorize way?

thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you give open code to end-user side (which is JS case) you should be ready to accept possibility of malicious code change client-side, that's obvious.
Since CouchDB manage write permissions on per-DB basis - malicios user will write to all docs in that DB if he has write permission there. 
Consider per-user DBs and then combine your multipart final docs server side only or consider other DB.